# How to implement a the tile seamless algorithm in JAVA?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Tile seamless is an image operation that is available in GIMP. It transforms the image so that it can cover a surface smoothly with a repeatable pattern. The edges will not be visible and the pieces will fit perfectly when tiled together. It makes senses for grass, floors, walls, etc... As far as the example shown in the GIMP documentation though, it is not good (the Taj Mahal https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filter-tile-seamless.html) but it gives an idea of how it works.
A transparent layer is applied over the image. It's a translation of half the size of the image (modulo image size) and the closer to the center, the more transparent it gets to show more of the original image. I took a look at the algorithm used in GIMP but it was pretty hard to read (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/-/blob/master/operations/common/tile-seamless.c).
So instead I remembered Pythagore to compute the distance to the center.
Then I apply a pro-rata to have an alpha between 0 and 255 :

- 0 => fully transparent => center
- 255 => fully opaque => corner

So here is the code :

```
public class TileSeamless {

    public static BufferedImage createSeamlessTile(BufferedImage inputImage) {
        int w = inputImage.getWidth();
        int h = inputImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage seamlessTile = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        seamlessTile.getGraphics().drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, null);
        seamlessTile.getGraphics().drawImage(createLayerImage(inputImage), 0, 0, null);
        return seamlessTile;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createLayerImage(BufferedImage inputImage) {
        int w = inputImage.getWidth();
        int h = inputImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage layerImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                Color color = new Color(inputImage.getRGB((x + w / 2) % w, (y + h / 2) % h));
                int alpha = (int) Math.round(255 * distanceToCenter(x, y, w, h) / distanceToCenter(0, 0, w, h));
                Color newColor = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), alpha);
                layerImage.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());
            }
        }
        return layerImage;
    }

    public static double distanceToCenter(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        double distanceToCenterX = x - w / 2d;
        double distanceToCenterY = y - h / 2d;
        return Math.sqrt(distanceToCenterX * distanceToCenterX + distanceToCenterY * distanceToCenterY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
        File outputFile = new File(args[1]);
        BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
        BufferedImage seamlessTile = TileSeamless.createSeamlessTile(inputImage);
        ImageIO.write(seamlessTile, "png", outputFile);
    }
```

The result is not too bad. It looks a bit different from the one produced by GIMP.
It's a bit blury.
Any idea how I can have a slighly more neat result?